# Does libsodium have error codes?

Tags: libsodium

Or any other mechanism to get the reason why a function is failing?

I'm calling `crypto_pwhash` and it's failing (returns -1) for no obvious reason, in fact the exact same code worked fine with an old version of libsodium. Having an error code would make debugging this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most functions do not return specific error codes when they fail.

History has shown that using different error codes for cryptographic operations can help attackers conduct devastating attacks.

`crypto_pwhash` allocates memory. So one reason it may fail is that you are running out of memory. In that case, `errno` will be set appropriately.

Also check that the parameters are within the allowed ranges. Functions such as `crypto_pwhash_bytes_min()`, `crypto_pwhash_memlimit_min()` and `crypto_pwhash_memlimit_min()` can come in handy. For example, given the purpose of that function, the output must be at least 128 bits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. errno is 0, and memory is plentiful. The output size is 256 bits, and I'm pretty sure opslimit (4) and memlimit (33MB) are within the allowed ranges (got them by using `crypto_pwhash_argon2i_memlimit_interactive`, and `crypto_pwhash_argon2i_opslimit_interactive`).

Comment: Ok, what is the full list of parameters you are using?

Comment: `crypto_pwhash(Key, KeySize, Passwd, Passwd.Size, Salt, 4, 33554432, 0)` where `Key` is 32 bytes, `Salt` is 16 bytes, and `Passwd` is variable-length. Have also tried `crypto_pwhash_argon2i` with the same parameters.

Comment: `0` is not a valid algorithm identifier.Use `crypto_pwhash_ALG_DEFAULT` for the last parameter.

Comment: The function `crypto_pwhash_alg_default` returns `0` for me. The headers indicate that this returns `crypto_pwhash_argon2i_ALG_ARGON2I13` which is defined as `1`, but using `1` doesn't seem to help either. (I have to manually define these symbols because I'm not using a language that understands C header files.)

Comment: Can you clarify what language you are using, or what specific bindings? If even `crypto_pwhash_alg_default()` doesn't return the correct value, these bindings seem to be completely broken. Maybe the way you call the functions and get the values back doesn't match the actual value sizes (`size_t` vs `uint32_t` vs `unsigned long long` for example).

Comment: In the RealBasic bindings, the type `UInt64` seems to be used for `size_t` and `UInt32` is used for `int`. I don't think this is correct. The former may not be true on Win32, and the later may not be true on Win64.

Comment: I'm writing/debugging the Realbasic binding. I'm pretty sure that `size_t` is unsigned, but I'm much less certain about the size. For the moment Win32 is the only target, but Win64 is likely to be added at a later date.

Comment: Progress! Changing the Memlimit parameter from a `UInt64` to a `UInt32` (and using algorithm id `1`) allows `crypto_pwhash` to succeed.